# How to initialize Java arrays of own types

Tags: java

I have this

```
Integer[] picIDs = {             
  R.drawable.whatever
  ,
  R.drawable.example
};
String[] picDescs = {
  "test1"
  ,
  "test2"      
};
```

Originally I wanted to make an array of a datatype containing fields "id" and "desc", but it seems impossible to initialize such arrays in declaration? (I was not able to Google how-to.) Is that really so?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

how about this?

```
YourType[] arr = {new YourType(12,"abc"), new YourType(13, "xyz")};
```

But make sure you have a Constructor of Yourtype which accepts an int (id) and String as arguments.

```
public class YourType{
String s;
int id;
    public YourType(int id, String s){
    this.id = id; 
    this.s = s;
    }

}
```

Comment: @SamIam  It's a class you created that you named `YourType`

Comment: @PremGenError  maybe you  should mention that somehow in your answer so that the OP doesn't get confused

Comment: @SamIam I think that's why @PremGenError named it `YourType`. Seems clear enough to me.

Comment: @GriffeyDog I bring it up because It appears, to me at least, that the OP isn't necessarily very use to `Java`, and things that might seem clear to you or me don't necessarily seem clear to everybody.

Answer (score 4):

You can do something like this:

```
public class Item {
    public int id;
    public String desc;
    public Item(int id, String desc) {
        this.id = id;
        this.desc = desc;
    }
}

Item[] items = {
    new Item(1, "one"),
    new Item(2, "two")
    // etc.
};
```

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried with some like this:

```
MyClass[] array={new MyClass(),new MyClass()};
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class DataType {  
    private Integer id;  
    private Stirng desc;  
    public DataType(Integer id, String desc) { this.id = id; this.desc = desc;}  
}  

DataType[] dt = {new DataType(id1, desc1), new DataType(id2, desc2) and so on};
```

So, you can define a class such as DataType and then just initialize anonymous instances of DataType in a DataType array.